# ckeditor cannot be edited after being covered by other external div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, jquery-ui-dialog

I was stucked with this bug for hours but still did not catch any clues to fix it:

I am trying to dynamically create dialogs after clicking the button and then attach the ckeditor to it. It worked fine when I dealt with only one instances, but after I enable multiple instances of CKeditor (bound to different div-based dialog elements, these functions of basic editing is lost...Here is the correspondent HTML before I cover/drag other elements around (sorry for not being able to upload image due to lack of reputation on stackoverflow) :

```
 <iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, wb_editor_7" aria-describedby="cke_467" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
    <html dir="ltr" lang="en"><head><title data-cke-title="Rich Text Editor, wb_editor_7">Rich Text Editor, wb_editor_7</title><style data-cke-temp="1">html{cursor:text;*cursor:auto}
img,input,textarea{cursor:default}</style><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/dashboard/lib/ckeditor-4.4.1/contents.css?t=E4KA"><style data-cke-temp="1">.cke_editable{cursor:text}.cke_editable img,.cke_editable input,.cke_editable textarea{cursor:default} .cke_contents_ltr a.cke_anchor,.cke_contents_ltr a.cke_anchor_empty,.cke_editable.cke_contents_ltr a[name],.cke_editable.cke_contents_ltr a[data-cke-saved-name]{background:url(http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/dashboard/lib/ckeditor-4.4.1/plugins/link/images/anchor.png?t=E4KA) no-repeat left center;border:1px dotted #00f;background-size:16px;padding-left:18px;cursor:auto;}.cke_contents_ltr img.cke_anchor{background:url(http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/dashboard/lib/ckeditor-4.4.1/plugins/link/images/anchor.png?t=E4KA) no-repeat left center;border:1px dotted #00f;background-size:16px;width:16px;min-height:15px;height:1.15em;vertical-align:text-bottom;}.cke_contents_rtl a.cke_anchor,.cke_contents_rtl a.cke_anchor_empty,.cke_editable.cke_contents_rtl a[name],.cke_editable.cke_contents_rtl a[data-cke-saved-name]{background:url(http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/dashboard/lib/ckeditor-4.4.1/plugins/link/images/anchor.png?t=E4KA) no-repeat right center;border:1px dotted #00f;background-size:16px;padding-right:18px;cursor:auto;}.cke_contents_rtl img.cke_anchor{background:url(http://127.0.0.1:8001/static/dashboard/lib/ckeditor-4.4.1/plugins/link/images/anchor.png?t=E4KA) no-repeat right center;border:1px dotted #00f;background-size:16px;width:16px;min-height:15px;height:1.15em;vertical-align:text-bottom;}
.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border,.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tr > td, .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tr > th,.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tbody > tr > td, .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tbody > tr > th,.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > thead > tr > td, .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > thead > tr > th,.cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tfoot > tr > td, .cke_show_borders  table.cke_show_border > tfoot > tr > th{border : #d3d3d3 1px dotted}</style></head><body contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="false">Hello world! Thank you for your help!</body></html>
```

After generating another ckeditor supported dialog, it did not fail to enable users to type and edit at the beginning, but once I drag the newly created one, it would be non-editable:

```
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Rich Text Editor, wb_editor_4" aria-describedby="cke_389" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe><html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Note that the difference is very astonishing in that the attribute of "contenteditable = true" disappeared in the HTML within CKEDITOR.

I have tried to make the textarea used to replace by CKEDITOR itself contenteditable, but still would not work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: it is because of the version of jquery ui, which needs to be 1.9 version to allow z-index control so that the iframe can be put front.